# requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the 'UIManager'

Tags: react-native

Does anyone knows how to fix this error. I have tried to install

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

and import it but still this error occurred. Thank you

Edit:

> Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
> react-native-gesture-handler - expected version: ~2.1.0 - actual version installed: 2.3.2
> Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
> To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo doctor --fix-dependencies,
> or install individual packages by running expo install [package-name ...]

My terminal show this too.

Comment: You should use `expo install` command instead of npm while using expo. So expo can install the supported version. `expo install react-native-gesture-handler`

Answer (score 2):

Please wrap your NavigationContainer with GestureHandlerRootView.

in `App.js`:

```
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                ...
            </NavigationContainer
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}
```

Comment: This should not be necessary as a rule of thumb